# Watin get elements where the id contains some text

Tags: c#, watin

How could i get the elements from a html page where the id begins with a string and ends with another string. Maybe you'll get my question by the following example:

HTML:

```
 <a href="#" onClick="" id="olla{randomtext}:id23">text</a>
```

Result:

```
I would like to click on links where id is like olla{randomtext}:id
```

Is there any possible solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
HtmlElement elementid;
elementid.Id="Your id"
//focus to selected id 
webbrowser.Document.GetElementById(ElementId).ScrollIntoView(true);
```

Comment: elementid.ID needs to start wit a string and it ends with another string. In the middle it will be random strings which are dynamic.

Comment: Element.id=startstring+randomnumber+endstring;